# Get unique elements from a 2D list

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I have a 2D list which I create like so:

`Z1 = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]`

I then proceed to populate this list, such that `Z1` looks like this:

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 1], [2, 5, 1]]`

I need to extract the *unique* `1x3` elements of `Z1`, without regard to order:

`Z2 = makeUnique(Z1) # The solution`

The contents of `Z2` should look like this:

`[[4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 1]]`

As you can see, I consider `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 1]` to be duplicates because I don't care about the order.

Also note that single numeric values may appear more than once across elements (e.g. `[2, 3, 1]` and `[2, 5, 1]`); it's only when all three values appear together more than once (in the same or different order) that I consider them to be duplicates.

I have searched dozens of similar problems, but none of them seems to address my exact issue. I'm a complete Python beginner so I just need a push in the right direction.

I have already tried :

`Z2= dict((x[0], x) for x in Z1).values()`
`Z2= set(i for j in Z2 for i in j)`

But this does not produce the desired behaviour.

Thank you very much for your help!

Louis Vallance

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the elements inside the sublists **does not** matter, you could use the following:

```
from collections import Counter

z1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 1], [2, 5, 1]]

temp = Counter([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in z1])

z2 = [list(k) for k, v in temp.items() if v == 1]
print(z2)  # [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5]]
```

Some remarks:

- sorting makes lists `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 1]` from the example equal so they get grouped by the `Counter`
- casting to `tuple` converts the `list`s to something that is hashable and can therefore be used as a `dictionary` key.
- the `Counter` creates a `dict` with the `tuple`s created above as keys and a value equal to the number of times they appear in the original `list`
- the final `list-comprehension` takes all those keys from the `Counter dictionary` that have a count of 1.

---

If the order **does** matter you can use the following instead:

```
z1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 1], [2, 5, 1]]

def test(sublist, list_):
    for sub in list_:
        if all(x in sub for x in sublist):
            return False
    return True

z2 = [x for i, x in enumerate(z1) if test(x, z1[:i] + z1[i+1:])]
print(z2)  # [[4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 1]]
```